# Manipulate the return of a child

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a `<FakeItem>` component that returns 2 components, title and content.

In the parent component `<Index>` I need it to separate those two components and render them separately.

This is a simplified example of my problem:

```
import { useId } from "react";

function FakeItem(props) {
  const id = useId();

  return (
    <>
      <a href={"#" + id}>{props.title}</a>
      <div id={id}>{props.content}</div>
    </>
  );
}

function Indice(props) {
  let FakeChild = props.children;

  // I already tried it...
  // FakeChild = <FakeChild />

  // I need to separate the child return (<FakeItem>)...
  const titulos = FakeChild[0]; // get <a>
  const conteudos = FakeChild[1]; // get <div>

  // They will be rendered separately
  return (
    <>
      <div className="titulos">{titulos}</div>
      <div className="conteudos">{conteudos}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Indice>
      <FakeItem title="Intro" content="Once upon a time..." />
    </Indice>
  );
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `FakeItem` if it's written in a way other than you want it? It's the wrong way to break up functionality--you want `<Title />` and `<Content />` components (which could also be used in `FakeItem` if you actually need a `FakeItem` component).

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your FakeItem into 2 different components.

Answer (score 0):

`props.children` prepresents the elements that where wrapped with the component so in your example :

```js
<Indice>
   <FakeItem title="Intro" content="Once upon a time..." />
</Indice>
```

since there is only one element within `<Indice>`
`props.children` in `<Indice>` component is not an array but an object.

However In this example it is an array

```
<Indice>
   <FakeItem title="Intro" content="Once upon a time..." />
   <FakeItem title="Intro2" content="Once upon a time2..." />
</Indice>
```

So `props.children` in your example is in fact the `<FakeItem/>` component so you still can access to its `props` :

```js
const childProps = props.children.props // {title: 'Intro', content: 'Once upon a time...'}
```